# Save users language php

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm building a multi language website and having some doubds about how to save the users language after the first visit. 
Ofcourse i'm intending to use cookies and here is my train of thoughts how to do it:

1. The website is being build with php in the mvc structure, every request is send to the index page and this index loads my bootstrap class.
2. In this bootstrap class I dismantle the url and would also like to check if there is a user existing user cookie.
3. If you have never visit the website, you first get the option to choose your prefered language, if this cookie does not exist the user did not select a language in the past and gets the option to choose one, if it is already filled in, just read the language and the date of his last visit.
4. Now put the right language in a session that starts at the bootstrap class and read it out every time the user requests a page so the website can call the correct view.

Now when the user would like to visit the secured area of my website, do i destroy his old session and generate a new one, and reload his language from the cookie for this session?

Maby this isn't the right way to look at it so I would love some advice from Stackoverflow.

Regards
Gijs

Comment: You don't have to destroy the entire cookie, just erase or overwrite the bits relevant to authentication from $_COOKIE and/or $_SESSION.

Comment: When you login and logout you just need to set (or destroy) the appropiate session variables and renew the session ID.